# Run parallel tests using xcodebuild on the same iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I have a project which has an Xcode Tests suite and I want to implement a CI system by using "xcodebuild ... tests" command. The only limitation that I have is the hardware. I'm limited to only 2 Macs and 2 iPads and I also want to build for Debug and Release. The problem is that I have different app flavors and I would like to run a part of them (e.g. all the flavours on debug) on one iPad and the others on the other iPad.
I tried to call multiple times "xcodebuild" commands using the "tests" argument, hoping that it would be parallelized, but the problem is that it kills the tests app instance that is running already on the device.

I spent some time searching for someone who did this, but the only thing that was close to what I need was the usage of multiple iOS Simulators which I'm not comfortable because real device testing is required for the project.

Is it doable to run parallel tests on the same device? Am I missing some arguments that I need to add to the xcodebuild command?

Answer (score 0):

No you can only run one test operation on 1 device at a time. Thats why people use multiple simulators as you can set them all to the same OS if you need to run the same test multiple times.

Not the answer you are looking for, but you could use Xcode server to have multiple bots, one for each flavour. If they all point to the same repo / branch, then they should all run one after the other. It would mean less manual effort building a tool to do it.

I also thought I read somewhere that with Xcode 10 you can load balance across multiple Xcode servers, but can't find a link to it. That might be helpful if you have 2 machines. If not you could duplicate the bots across both Xcode servers. Maybe using the API to control the creation of bots?

[Xcode server setup guide](https://medium.com/xcblog/xcode-server-with-xcode-10-124013cbedbc)